# Vim : How to add a new line

Tags: vim

I want to add a line break in vim from line 59 to the end of file.

```
- 0021: Paralleism
- 0022: Mazimum Sum Sequence
- 0023: Circles Intersection
- 0024: Physical Experiments
```

to this

```
- 0021: Paralleism

- 0022: Mazimum Sum Sequence

- 0023: Circles Intersection

- 0024: Physical Experiments
```

I tried the following  but it doesn't work.

```
:59,Gs/$/$\n/
```

How can I achieve this with vim substitute?

Comment: I reopened this question because it isn't an exact duplicate of the other.  This question also deals with ranges, not just replacing newlines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish it with this:

```
:59,$s/$/\r/
```

Comment: Sorry. It's `\r` instead.

Comment: you can also use <C-v><CR>

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this would be:

```
:59,$g/./norm o
```

Alternatively if you wanted to do this to all lines beginning with a - you could do:

```
:g/- /norm o
```

Answer (score 3):

Time for global:

```
:59,$g/^/pu_
```

For more see:

```
:h :g
:h :pu
:h registers
```